# What does "If it wouldn't be" mean?

Tags: meaning

Drill Sergeant says to Forrest Gump:

> Drill Sergeant: **If it wouldn't be a waste** of such a damn fine enlisted
> man,  I'd recommend you for OCS, Private Gump. You are gonna be a
> general some day, Gump.

What does "If it wouldn't be" mean?

Comment: The sergeant implies that it _would_ be a waste of a good soldier to do so, but if that _wasn't_ the case he would recommend him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCS probably means Officer Cadet School: that is training to become an officer in the Army.  By contrast, an "enlisted man" is a low-rank soldier. Private is the lowest rank in the Army.

The Sergeant is saying with some dialect and heavy irony:

> You are a very good low-rank soldier.
>
> You deserve to go to Officer Cadet School, to train as an
> officer, as I think you have the potential to be a General of the
> Army.
>
> But then you would be a school and not fighting in this war.
>
> And that would be a waste of your talent, since you are very good at
> fighting.
>
> So I won't send you to OCS!

To begin to understand Forrest Gump, you need to realise it is a satire.  It is making a comment about the nature of the American army.